# Is there an online citation generator with wikipedia citation formatting?

Tags: citations

I am aware of numerous online citation generators that are resonably comprehensive in their databases and have a diversity of formats such as MLA, APA, Chicago, etc. However I have been unable to locate one that will generate a wikipedia markup version. Does one exist? It would sure be helpful for a lot of wikipedia editors - myself included.

By wikipedia citation formatting I mean: < ref>stuff< /ref> markup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is probably going to be closed as off-topic, but I think the question is still worth answering.

General tools:

- [Makeref](http://tools.wmflabs.org/makeref/)

Specific sources:

- [DOI Wikipedia reference generator](http://reftag.appspot.com/doiweb.py)
- [New York Times Wikipedia reference generator](http://reftag.appspot.com/nytweb.py)
- [Wikipedia citation tool for Google Books](http://reftag.appspot.com/)

[Source, with many other tools listed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Citation_tools)

Comment: We except more then a link contained in an answer. Other websites already answer questions with poor responses like that.  If you are going to answer this question, list the tools on this website, then provide a source for the material.

Comment: Alright. Will do.

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. Thankyou

Comment: @user81916 You're welcome.

Comment: This works for me:
https://irl.github.io/bibwiki/